# Upload and Browse button missing in CMS WYSIWYG on Magento v1.9.21

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, cms-block

I have an issue where you upload an image via the CMS Pages and the Browse and Upload buttons are missing.

I have tried following without any success ;

- added back in the SWF files that are removed by patch 8788
- changed the folder permissions to 777
- clearing Magento cache and reindexed
- Tried in another browser and Incognito

Any ideas that I have not thought of?

Answer (score 0):

Try in different browser. Because it might be flash player issue in your current browser. (Sorry, I couldn't gave comment this one to your thread due to low popularity. That's why I'm putting as answer.)

Comment: Why up vote is when its not solved the issue, I already tried it in various browsers and its not solved the issue.

Comment: Any other ideas what it could be?

Comment: Have a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178378/image-uploading-issue-after-applying-patch-8788